# Is there an iPhone UDP tutorial?

Tags: iphone, udp

I've been googling for several hours before asking this question. I need to get acquainted with the very basics of UDP programming for iPhone but i just can't find anything helpful. Could you please:

1)Give me a link to something like tutorial if such a thing exists somewhere.

or

2)Explain very basics of UDP programming for iPhone in plain language

or

3)Maybe you're able to suggest something helpful for me what i'm not aware of. If there ARE lots of people who knows how to deal with UDP for iPhone then there MUST be a way to learn it.

I really need your help. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following links, you will definitely find the solution :

1. http://www.kat.ph/wibit-net-programming-in-objective-c-simple-iphone-app-t5685121.html
2. [Help with Sending/ Receiving UDP packets - C Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176273/help-with-sending-receiving-udp-packets-c-sockets)
3. (not sure but in .h file it is written iPhone Simulator so giving you this link) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

If anyone searches for this, I think the link 1. above is dead ... try
[programming_objective-c](http://www.wibit.net/curriculum/courses/programming_objective-c)