# Send "Hello World" message via udp from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, udp

I am new to objective C and I need to send a simple message via UDP. The server part is working cause it is implemented in C#.

The server code in C# is:

```
 var server = new UdpClient(8585);
 var groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.120"),8585);
 byte[] bytes = server.Receive(ref groupEP);
```

and the client part in c# is:

```
   System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient client;     
client = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient("192.168.0.120",8585);    
client.Send(new byte[]{1,2,3,4},4);
```

how can I do the same client part in objective c? I know there are a lot of tutorials on the internet such as [this library](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/). when I import that library to my project I do not know how to instantiate a new object. I have tried:

```
 [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithSocketQueue:... ??? I don't know how to initialize it.
```

I will appreciate if someone can show me a simple example of how could I replicate the client part into objective c.

Comment: here you find an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176273/help-with-sending-receiving-udp-packets-c-sockets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

download GCDAsyncUdpSocket from [here](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/). then you may send packets as:

```
 GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket ; // create this first part as a global variable
 udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

 NSData *data = [ 
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%Hello Wold" 
                    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                ];

[udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@"192.168.10.111" port:550 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

Comment: the project already move to Github https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Comment: what if the ip address varies

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a sample project called [UDPEcho](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Listings/Read_Me_About_UDPEcho_txt.html). Although it's a Mac project, it relies mainly on classes from Core Foundation which is also available on iOS and the lessons it contains should apply equally well to iOS.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. It works perfect when I run the Mac project. When I copy the same libraries and call the same method it does not work on the iPhone. I don't get any errors though. Could it be that I am doing something wrong or it just works on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

First, have a read [of this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301) which outlines some of the fundamental types of network communication available in iOS.

In particular, Apple have an example of network communication using sockets and the `NSStream` class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008979-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

You *can* use the normal BSD socket API but it is discouraged because they don't work with certain iOS network features like VPN on-demand. If this is of no consequence then you can check [here](http://developerweb.net/) for examples of how to use sockets in C.

From personal experience, it's not as easy as what you've got in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem using monotouch. I just do it the same way I will do it in c#:

```
 System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient client;
 client = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient("192.168.0.120",550);
 client.Send(new byte[]{1,2,3,4},4);
```

I don't want to pay for the license though. it will cost $400. If I where to have more than 3 lines of code I might have think of it.